# Embedding standard C++ into a .NET application

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, interop, managed-c++

I want to write an algorithmic library in standard, platform-independent C++.

Can I then take the same C++ code and compile it for .NET so that a C# application can use the library?
If not, what is the easiest way to achieve this kind of interop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three ways to expose your library to easily be called from managed code:

- write a C++/CLI wrapper for it that contains a `public ref class` - the C# code will call methods of this class, which will call native methods of your library
- expose a C-style function from your library as a DLL - the C# code will use P/Invoke to call the function
- write a COM component in C++ that uses your library and call it from the C# code by adding a COM reference to it.

That third one, COM, I include only for completeness. It wouldn't be my first choice. Or my third. It's one thing if the COM component exists, it's another to write it just for this.

Between the first two it's a matter of who else might use this library. If the C# code is the only one using it, do what you like. But for example you might have 15 or 20 native methods that set various properties, followed by a `go` or `execute` method that does the actual work. Because managed-native interop has a cost, I would tell you to write one C++/CLI function that takes 20 parameters, calls the various native functions and then calls the `go` or `execute`. This gives you a chunkier interface instead of chatty and reduces your interop costs.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot directly interface between C# and standard C++. However, you can use your C++ library inside a C++/CLI wrapper which makes the functionality available in .NET managed code (and thus C#).

Simply write the wrapper as a C++/CLI library that exposes a .NET API and includes the code from your standard C++ library (but unfortunately this cannot be statically linked, as far as I know).

Answer (score -1):

You can call native C/C++ libraries from any .NET language using pinvoke.  Here's a quick tutorial from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).  You can also create a COM dll in C++ that you can reference directly from within C# using COM Interop.  Unless you need the advantages of COM, pinvoke is a much easier route to go.

And of course, as Konrad stated, you wrap the C++ dll using a managed C++ solution.

As an example, check out http://www.pinvoke.net/ for samples on how you call win32 api's from C#.

From the MSDN link above (modified per the comment below):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class PlatformInvokeTest
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int puts(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        string m);
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern int _flushall();


    public static void Main() 
    {
        puts("Hello World!");
        _flushall();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can call native C libraries, and C++ libraries pretending to be C libraries. You can not `#include <vector>` and get cracking from C#.

Comment: I never claimed you could.  The original question asked how you could interop with a native library.  The solution I presented is perfectly valid.

Comment: Your P/Invoke signatures are not correct -- `puts` and `_flushall` are exported with the `__cdecl` calling convention, but the `DllImport` attribute uses `__stdcall` unless you specify otherwise. (I understand the error was copied from the MSDN page you linked to, but you may as well fix it here IMO.)

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks for info. I checked around and it is interesting that no samples anywhere show the calling convention specified with either of those methods (at least that I saw). I tested the sample code using both calling conventions and both worked. I'll modify the answer to have the appropriate convention. Would that affect the performance?

Comment: On some platforms the CLR throws an exception about stack imbalance, on others it's able to correct the imbalance automatically. I suspect that correction isn't free... Regarding _showing_ the calling conventions, it's the fact that it's _not_ shown that's elucidating here -- the default for C/C++ is `__cdecl` and the default for .NET P/Invoke is `__stdcall`, and given that nothing is specified on either side, the defaults must be in play.