# Using an unmanaged C++ library with a .NET API

Tags: c++, .net, interop, pinvoke, unmanaged

I have a project where I must make use of an API to read file of a proprietary filetype.  It is closed source, just a bunch of DLLs that can be added as a reference in my project (currently I am using C#).   However, I also wish to make use of a C++ library, OpenMS (http://open-ms.sourceforge.net/) in order to manage and analyse the data I obtain.  I have read a bit about P/Invoke and creating a wrapper (and some others suggested other methods such as this: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_managed/interop/article.php/c6867 ) but I am not sure how I should go about this and what the best way would be, especially as most examples I have seen are very simple and this library has many complex data types etc.  Is it possible to automate the process of creating a wrapper as the library is very large?

Comment: Managed Extensions for C++ has been totally replaced by C++/CLI.  Information from before 2005 is totally useless as a result.  There are many [questions about using C++/CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B-cli%5D+wrapper) already here on StackOverflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding standard C++ into a .NET application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361866/embedding-standard-c-into-a-net-application)

Answer (score 1):

You don't add unmanaged DLLs as references; that only works for managed DLLs written in a .NET language.

If you're using C#, P/Invoke is your only option. Yes, the difficulty and time consumed by doing so will increase proportionately with the complexity of the library. You will need to ensure that there are managed equivalents of all the data types used by the library, defining them yourself explicitly if necessary. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any way to automating this process.

If switching to C++/CLI is an option, you will have a much easier time as you can consume the unmanaged library directly, mixing it with your .NET code.

Comment: I have never really used C++/CLI but I will look into it.  Windows programming still baffles me on a regular basis as I have mainly worked in Linux in the past.  If I can still make use of the dlls that make up this API then I imagine it would be possible to convert my project.

Comment: @Travis: You're going to have an extraordinarily hard time adjusting to Windows programming so long as you continue to conflate managed and unmanaged code. They're completely different beasts, generally incompatible. It would really behoove you to start thinking of them as completely different. Because you have to jump through hoops to mix them, this is a somewhat advanced endeavor best reserved for someone with familiarity with at least *one* of them. :-) Just for clarity, C++/CLI is a set of extensions to the C++ language provided by Microsoft for interoperability with native and .NET code.

Comment: P/invoke really isn't an option if the library interface uses C++ features

Answer (score 1):

Mono guys in fact develop something different from P/Invoke or C++/CLR and may be more friendly to C# developers,

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Dec-19.html

The question is how mature it is right now, but you can play with it and learn,

https://github.com/mono/cxxi

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this.  I ill look into it as it certainly seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

Not shure, may be this tool help you - [swig](http://www.swig.org/)